# App crashing when updating app from app store after codebase changed from titanium to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, app-store, titanium

My application was previously written in Titanium. Now, I have released a new version where the code is written in Swift. Now after the user updates his app to this version and starts the app, it crashes. Then it again starts running fine when the user deletes and installs the app back. What can be the best way to detect this change in the app? I have thought of a solution. I can check if some key in NSUserDefaults is set or not and delete and refresh and start again.

Comment: Have you got logs for this installations?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because titanium save something in the iOS memory-cache for inizialitze it. And then when users delete the application delete this cache too, maybe a good whay for fix this is clean the cache when inizialize your new application for first time.